# How much does the architecture of data affect the speed of a query

Tags: neo4j

I have the following nodes and relationships in Neo4j database.
The grey and the pink node are furtherly connected with more nodes. Running the following query:

```
 MATCH (n:RealNode {gid:'$obj_id'})-[:CONTAINS*..3]-(z) 
 RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID"
```

I get a result very fast (the node n:RealNode is not one of the nodes in the image).

If I increase the depth to 4 like:

```
   MATCH (n:RealNode {gid:'$obj_id'})-[:CONTAINS*..4]-(z) 
   RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID"
```

The response gets extremely slow. I will never get a response with depth 5 etc.

The depth 4 is actually the relationship between the blue-pink node. So my question is: can the architecture of data (in this case) affect in such a great level the speed of the query? If yes what should I do?
I have tried to run the query also using parameters but the result was the same. Also the gid of n:RealNode is an indexed value.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architecture of your data has a **huge**, no...**massive** impact on query performance.  There's a lot you can do with improving performance by reformulating your query, but you can do even more than that by changing your data model.

The model needs to be chosen in a way that's an accurate depiction of the real-world domain, but it often also has to make certain concessions to usage patterns.  If you know you're going to do certain queries over and  over, it makes sense to choose a data model that makes it easy for the DBMS to answer that query.  In the RDBMS world, that entire line of thinking gets summarized in the word "[denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)".  In graph databases, the concept is the same but the way you go about it is different.

The thing to keep in mind when adjusting your data model is that neo4j is good at traversing relationships fast, and that with all queries, the less data you have to consider, the faster the query will go.

So in your case, I don't know how many nodes branch off of each other node by a `:CONTAINS` relationship, but I'm guessing that at each level of the hierarchy you have many items below it.  So going from level 4 to level 5 probably doesn't just add a fixed number of additional nodes, but if say each level of the hierarchy has 3x the number of nodes as the level above, the deeper you go, the more you're multiplying how much data you have to consider.   If it's 10x...then ouch.

You have many different options.  One is to create short-cut relationships, and "pre-materialize" the query.  Imagine creating `:grandfather` and `:greatgrandfather` relationships to "hop" levels of the tree.  That would make it faster.  Another way would be to filter intermediate nodes, or the return nodes, so that you're not considering everything, but some subset.

In the end, really huge queries will always take longer than really small ones. You must first begin with a careful understanding of what data you want, and how often you have to run this query.  I would not attempt to optimize your data model for infrequently run queries, but if you do this all the time, you should look at your options.  Your query to me looks like it's going to return a whole lot of data no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The truth is that I tend to run this query quite often. Also the nodes and relations shown in the image are the worst case. The other depth levels have one to one relation or maximum 1 to 2. I am new in the graph database world and not very familiar with many of the terminology you use. Do you have any sources for the short-cut relationships or the filtering method?

Comment: Hmm. I see what you mean now. So if I have for nodes: A B C D  and all of them are connected like A->B->C->D you suggest to create also a direct relationship from A->D (or C) and then run two different queries (or even one merged) with a lower level of depth. Right?

Comment: But still dont quite get your second suggestion. The filtering.

Comment: yes, you're right about the first one.  Shortcuts are instead of `A->B->C->D` create `A->D`.  The second one, filtering, is say reducing the possible `z` values, like this:  `MATCH (n:RealNode {gid:'$obj_id'})-[:CONTAINS*..3]-(z) WHERE z.field=5` - this means only those `z` objects would be returned.  Fewer nodes to consider, faster query.

Comment: If this answers your question satisfactorily, please mark it answered.